# remote system with email verification in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, email-verification

The app is kind of like a parent disciplines child app where the child/person does chores and gets points. What I need help with is I am using a Firebase data base just to let you know. What I need is when the child presses the button to redeem their points it sends an email with the verification link in it. Once the verification link is pressed it awards the points and updates the counter. Please note that the value or amount of points will be written through a form that the parents So my general idea would be to use the on click listener option I set below but my issue is to define a function that will send the verification link and then write code like when task is successful award points to the counter.

```
      if(task.isSuccessful){
           counter ++ button.val

     ButtonVerify.onClick listener
        switch (view.getId)){
                case R.id.ButtonVerifiy;
                verifypoints();
             }
```

Could anyone help me write a code that will make this work?

Thank you everyone

Comment: `when the child presses the button to redeem their points it sends an email` Who should send that email?

Comment: I suggest you to try to code what you write in Android Studio and then post the resulting code here replacing that _pseudo-code_ ... it will give a better idea of what you mean.